# Acer A500 internal storage is not auto-mounted by Ubuntu

Tags: linux, internal-storage, 3.0-honeycomb

I just got my Acer A500 and have problems accessing the it's storage from my ubuntu machines.

If I try it with Win7 in VirtualBox it is automatically mounted without requiring any actions on the tablet itself.

Ubuntu accepts the USB device (it can be passed to vbox) but nothing further. The only dmesg entry is:

```
[119174.117100] usb 1-1.2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 22
```

I'm able to mount and use other usb storage devices.

Comment: Can you boot ubuntu off a livecd directly onto the hardware and see if it works then?

Comment: I know there's a guide on XDA for the Xoom. Could be the same kind of procedure for the A500 since they're both running Honeycomb. You can take a look at it [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=981774) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu, your device needs to be manually identified to the udev system:

As root:
Create or edit `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` and add this line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0502″, MODE="0666"
```

Then:

```
# chmod a+rx /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
# restart udev
udev start/running, process 3793
```

This works for my Sidekick on my Ubuntu 10.04 system.

Answer (score -2):

Im not able to mount but ADB push/pull works... see this thread http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html